# Trigger events defined after DOM load - JIRA open new issue modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, jira

I am building a third party plugin to the popular platform Atlassian JIRA and where I have implemented a calendar. However when I click on a day outside any event, it triggers a function which will trigger the `#create_link event`.

When that event gets fired a new modal window opens and the user may fill out a new issue. The thing is that I want to change the issuetype field and then fill in one field automatically. However, I have no idea how to generate a new window with these result (I don't think it's possible) and therefore my only option was Javascript events.

This is my code so far:

```
jQuery.when(AJS.$('#create_link').trigger('click')).done(function() {
    jQuery.when(jQuery('#issuetype-field').trigger('click')).done(function() {
        jQuery('.aui-list-item-li-event').find('a').trigger('click');
    });
});

//I have also tried to use `.then`
```

The thing is, the triggers work when run separately in console but it seems like the `jQuery.when` doesn't. Because the next event triggers long before the window has been loaded.

**What I need is a way to wait to trigger the last 2 events by using callbacks on the triggers or what not**. How can I solve this problem? Also, if anyone know how to create a new issue window with js in Jira that is also a very acceptable answer.

Comment: not very sure what exactly do you want. but why you making custom and not using Jira's issue collector?

Comment: if you make this comment as an answer I can accept it. Even if it didn't solve all our issues, it solved most. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Jira issue collector would make your task much simpler. You can configure it to receive feedback or bug reports etc.

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Using+the+Issue+Collector

The integration of the issue collector is merely adding a script tag in your `HTML` page